# OnLoad Banner Zoomout

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I'm trying to recreate a `zoom-out` animation on an image on page load, like the Wikipedia app.  I've got it working so on hover, the image gently zooms out, but I don't know how to work it into an independently firing function.  I tried creating a jquery function that just added a class with the new scale but that didn't seem to work.

Can anyone help?

```js
//Function I attempted to Use

$(function() {
$('.photo').addClass('shrink')
});
```

```css
.photo {
 height: 350px;
 widthL 350px;
 border: 1px solid;
 overflow:hidden;
}

.photo img {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 transition: all .5s;
 transform: scale(1.2);
}

.photo:hover img {
 transform: scale(1);
}

/*
.shrink {
  transform: scale(1)
}

*/
```

```html
<div class="photo">
 <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/2b/05/14/2b05140a776f25a8047c88fbe2bcbdb9.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an animation instead of a simple transition.
Something like this

```css
@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
    0%   {transform: scale(1);}
    100% {transform: scale(0.8); }
}

h1 {
    -webkit-animation: zoom 5s 1;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hey there, I'm using ANIMATION</h1>
```

Of course you need to change the  with your image :)

Comment: Is it possible to add an ease or an ease-in-out to an animation or is it just built in?

Comment: Sure! Just add "opacity: 0" to 0% frame and "opacity: 1" to the 100% frame :)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change the `.shrink` in your CSS to `.shrink img` (and uncomment it, of course), you're targeting the div and not the image.

[Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mq9ron4y/)
Note you might also want to add a document.ready() to ensure the elements are in place.